# Coding a Scatter plot with smooth lines in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to code for a Scatter Plot using smooth lines with VBA.
I am trying to take data off of a worksheet and create a scatter plot with lines and no markers in the same workbook different sheet using VBA.

This is part snapshot of my worksheet

[image]

The values below 247 and between 263 to 455 in column A will have corresponding -1.75 in column B.

The x values are in range `A1:A401`

y-values are in range `B1:B401`

Also I want to have title to my graph and X and Y axis labelled. I am having trouble figuring how to get the y-values to plot with the x-values instead of excel making two seperate lines on the chart.

This is graph I need

[image]

This is the code I have used

```
Set xData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A" & LastRow_this)
Set yData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B1:B" & LastRow_this)

Set GraphRange = Union(xData, yData)

'Create a chart
  Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes.AddChart2

'Give chart some data
  cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=GraphRange

'Determine the chart type
  cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
```

This is what it gives me in Excel.

[image]

How can I get the desired result ?

Also what can I do if the range is dynamic ?

Comment: Add the chart using `Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes.AddChart2(, xlXYScatterChartLines)` so the chart starts out as the type you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub CreateChart()
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsChart As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim xData As Range, yData As Range, GraphRange As Range
Dim cht As Shape

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsChart = Sheets(1)
Set wsData = Sheets(2)
LastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set xData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
Set yData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B1:B" & LastRow)

Set GraphRange = Union(xData, yData)

'Create a chart
Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes.AddChart2(, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers)

'Give chart some data
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=GraphRange
cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 5
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 5 where 5 would be weight of the line which you can change as per your requirement.

Comment: cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 5

Comment: Did you try the above line? I tested it and it works for me with version 2013.

Comment: I tried(copy pasted the same) ...I am not using SeriesCollection...Is that the cause of the error ?

Comment: The line I suggested should be inserted just before the line Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Comment: The graph is like this ___/\\____ .
The horizontal lines are still not adjusted for line thickness.Only /\ is adjusted.

Comment: No, this is not the case. See the image I have added in the answer.

Comment: Yes I added xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers as chart type and it worked perfectly...Thanks a great deal..
Can you tell me what 
AddChart2(, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers) does ?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked. The first argument which is skipped is the style of the chart whereas the second one is the chart type. Please take a minute to accept the solution to mark your question as Solved. :)

Answer (score 2):

With a scatter chart you don't want to use "GraphRange" for the whole chart. Depending on the data and the phase of the moon, Excel will try to plot the X and the Y data as individual series, which is not what you want.

Instead, edit or insert each series separately and set the range for the X and the Y values. Also you need `xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers` as the chart type.

Try using the macro recorder to select the range, add a scatter chart with smoothed lines. Then inspect the code. This will give you valuable pointers about the changes you need to make to your code.

Comment: How can I accomplish that using SeriesCollection

Answer (score 0):

My code is

```
Sub setChart()
Dim LastRow_this As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet, chtWs As Worksheet
Dim xData As Range, yData As Range
Dim Cht As Chart

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set chtWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    With Ws
        LastRow_this = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set xData = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow_this)
        Set yData = .Range("B1:B" & LastRow_this)
    End With

    Set Cht = chtWs.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    With Cht
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .HasLegend = False
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .XValues = xData
            .Values = yData
        End With
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 50
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 460
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 50
    End With

End Sub
```